# OpenBSD and limiting login to local only like in FreeBSD's login.access(5)

Tags: security, login, openbsd

I am using OpenBSD as my desktop.  I don't want to login to my machine remotely, and I don't want anyone else to login remotely.  In FreeBSD there is a file called [login.access(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.access&sektion=5) that can be used to prevent remote logins, and limit login to local only.  How can I accomplish the same thing in OpenBSD?

I've read the man pages for [login(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=login&sektion=1&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current) and login.conf(5) and it's possible I'm missing something, but I don't see the answer there.

Comment: Welcome to [security.se].  Please read our [faq].  As it stands, your question is off-topic for this site.  While the question here is indeed about securing an Information System, the intent of the question is toward implementation.  This site is more geared for risk analysis and threat modeling.  I'm going to suggest that this be moved to another site, perhaps [sf], [su], or [unix.se].  If deemed appropriate, a moderator will migrate the existing question for you - please do not cross-post.

Comment: I'm not sure but restricting remote logins with `login.access` could have nothing to do against just remote command execution (like `ssh host cmd`)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenBSD has counterpart named [login.conf](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=login.conf&sektion=5&arch=i386&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current)

Take a look at [login_reject](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=login_reject&sektion=8&arch=i386&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current) for e. g..